# HTML UI input slider being pushed out of position

Tags: html, css, slider, stylesheet

[image: UI screenshot showing slider being put out of place]

Hi guys, in the above image there is a screenshot of a UI I am working on for the purposes of a college assignment which involves manipulating the DOM using JQuery.

Currently I have the logic working and I am now trying to tidy my code and enhance the UI. I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask this question as strictly speaking I do not think it is a programming issue but I thought I'd take my chances!

For some reason the slider in the image above is being pushed out of place and I have no idea why. Does anyone know what might be causing this??

The stylesheet is huge so I don't want to include it, unless you need to see a certain part.

Any help is much appreciated.

In the image the circle shows the slider trailing off the UI. The arrow points to where It should be located. The underlined slider is how it should also be appearing.

Comment: Gonna need to see some HTML & CSS for this I think.  Even if it means putting the large CSS into a fiddle.

Comment: Ok will do that. In college at the moment, can do when I go home